# Telegram Bot - Is there a way to drop incoming messages when my bot server is down?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I'm currently working on a Telegram Bot, but when I shut down the server and turn it on again, the bot reacts to every commands that was sent while the server was down all at once. Is there a way to drop the command messages while the server is down? Or is there a different way?

Comment: you must be using `longPolling`, that's most probably why it responds to the early messages. please share a sample snippet how you start the bot so that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to drop all updates. Quickly setting and deleting a webhook clears all pending updates. So the next time you start polling, there are no new updates.

You can do this by calling in the following order:

1. [https://api.telegram.org/bot[TOKEN]/setWebhook?url=https://postman-echo.com/post](https://api.telegram.org/bot%5BTOKEN%5D/setWebhook?url=https://postman-echo.com/post)
2. [https://api.telegram.org/bot[TOKEN]/deleteWebhook](https://api.telegram.org/bot%5BTOKEN%5D/deleteWebhook)

So before starting the server you can have a script that calls these methods!

You can test this in the web browser itself by observing:

- [https://api.telegram.org/bot[TOKEN]/getUpdates](https://api.telegram.org/bot%5BTOKEN%5D/getUpdates)